# How to replace a text with row count with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a dynamic table . that i'd add number for each tr. how can i replace the hello text with count of each tr with javascript?
here is my snippet of table:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Rownumber</th> 
    <th>Name</th> 
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Hello</th> 
    <th>A</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th> 
    <th>B</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th> 
    <th>C</th> 
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `<td>` instead of `<th>` after the header row.

```js
$('tr').each(function(index, row){
     $(row).children('td').first().text(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Rownumber</th> 
    <th>Name</th> 
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Hello</td> 
    <td>A</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td> 
    <td>B</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td> 
    <td>C</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem -

```js
var table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
var rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
let index = 0;

for( let row of rows){
  for( let col of row.querySelectorAll("th")){
    if( col.textContent == 'Hello'){
      col.textContent = index;
    }
  }
  index++;
}
```

```html
<table  border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Rownumber</th> 
    <th>Name</th> 
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Hello</th> 
    <th>A</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th> 
    <th>B</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th> 
    <th>C</th> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the `<tr>` elements within the table. Then loop through the `<tr>`s and starting with the second one, replace its first child's text with the index of the current `<tr>`.

```
let tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("tr")

tableRows.forEach((tr, index) => {

    if(index === 0) {
        //Do nothing bc you don't want to remove the text in the first table row
    } else {
        let firstChild = tr.children[0]
        firstChild.innerText = index
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find("td:first")` to get the numbers that would replace "Hello". Also, since its a table, you need to use `td`. `th` are used for headers:

```js
$('tr').each(function(index, row) {
  $(row).find("td:first").text(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Rownumber</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```